# D3 - Combining arrays

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using this D3 code which works absolutely fine.

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 700,
    r = 12,
    gravity = 0.1,
    distance = 100,
    charge = -800,
    fill = d3.scale.category10(),

    nodes=[
        {name:"Start", performer:"admin", status:1, timestamp:"16-Aug-2014"}, 
        {name:"Dept Approver", performer:"admin", status:1, timestamp:"23-Aug-2014"}, 
        {name:"Amount>20", performer:"admin", status:1, timestamp:"23-Aug-2014"},
        {name:"Div Approver", performer:"admin", status:3, timestamp:"23-Aug-2014"}, 
        {name:"Section Aprpover", performer:"admin", status:1, timestamp:"23-Aug-2014"}, 
        {name:"End", performer:"admin", status:2, timestamp:"23-Aug-2014"}
        ],

    // the relations shown can be calculated using
    // formulas from either 1 or 2 other quantities
    links=[
        {"source":0,"target":1,"value":1}, {"source":1,"target":2,"value":1}, 
        {"source":2,"target":3,"value":1}, {"source":2,"target":4,"value":1}, 
        {"source":3,"target":5,"value":1}, {"source":4,"target":5,"value":1}
    ];

// create the canvas for the model
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// d3 provides the calculations to animate the model
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(gravity)
    .distance(distance)
    .charge(charge)
    .size([width, height]);

// add data, and start the animation
force.nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .start();

// add classnames to links for styling
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");

// enable drag of nodes
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);

// draw circles
var circle=node.append("svg:circle").attr("r", r - .75).style("fill", function(d) {
        return fill(d.status);
    }).style("stroke", function(d) {
        return d3.rgb(fill(d.status)).darker();
    }).call(force.drag);

// add tooltip so it shows the unit and formula
circle.append("svg:title").text(function(d, i) { return "Performer: " + d.performer + ", Timestamp: " + d.timestamp; });


// create arrowheads (end markers)
// three type of styles can be made for each group
// this feature is not used
svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data([1,2,3])
  .enter().append("svg:marker")
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 22)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("fill-color","#cccccc")
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

// attach markers
var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.value; })
    .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.value + ")"; });

// create a group for text elements
var text = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("g")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("svg:g");

// create shadow in white
text.append("svg:text")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("class", "shadow")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name;}
  );

// create name on top of shadow
text.append("svg:text")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name;}
  );

// put the symbol, e.g. kg inside the circle
/*text.append("svg:text")
      .attr("dx", -4)
      .attr("dy", 2)
      .attr("fill", "#ffffff")
      .text(function(d) { return d["symbol"]?d.symbol:"";}
  ); */

force.on("tick", function(d) {
     path.attr("d", function(d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = 0; // straight lines (0=straight, 1=round)
        // alternatively use dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy); for similar arcs
        return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
      });
    
      circle.attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      });
    
      text.attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      });

});

// when clicked redraw the diagram
d3.select("#chart").on("click", function() {
  nodes.forEach(function(o, i) {
    o.x += (Math.random() - .5) * 100;
    o.y += (Math.random() - .5) * 100;
  });
  force.resume();
});
```

```css
.link {
  stroke: #fcfcfc;
}

.node text {
  pointer-events: none;
  font: 12px Calibri, Arial;
}
path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

marker#licensing {
  fill: green;
}

path.link.licensing {
  stroke: green;
}

path.link.resolved {
  stroke-dasharray: 0,2 1;
}

circle {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}

text.shadow {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
      <div id="chart"></div>
  </body>
```

It has two arrays, nodes and links.

I am wondering if it is possible to combine these two arrays into a single array. It would make it easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: Those 2 arrays are completely different in contents... How on earth would it be easier to maintain if you're mixing types of data?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am looking to do something like {source:"Start", target:"Dept Approver", performer:"admin", status:1, timestamp:"16-Aug-2014"}. That way, how the nodes connect can be found in one place, instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a `map`-like function, such as:

```
var result = []
for (var idx in nodes) {
  var link = links[idx],
      node = nodes[idx]
  result.push({
    source: nodes[link.source].name,
    target: nodes[link.target].name,
    performer: nodes[link.???].performer,
    // etc...
  })
}
```

I would also suggest checking out `Underscore`, `LoDash`, or `Lazy.js`, libraries that make these kind of data transformations more elegant.